# XSS triggering trouble

Tags: php, javascript, xss, zen-cart

So one of the sites I'm working on apparently has an xss vulnerability.

The normal html is this:

```
<form name="contact_us" action="somewhere" method="post">
<div id="contactUsNoticeContent" class="content"></div>
<fieldset id="contactUsForm">
<legend>Contact Us</legend>
<div class="alert forward">* Required information</div>
<label class="inputLabel" for="contactname">Full Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="contactname" size="40" id="contactname"><span class="alert">*
</span><br class="clearBoth">
<label class="inputLabel" for="email-address">Email Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" size="40" id="email-address"><span class="alert">*
</span><br class="clearBoth">

<label for="enquiry">Message:<span class="alert">*</span></label>
<textarea name="enquiry" cols="30" rows="7" id="enquiry"></textarea>
</fieldset>

<div class="buttonRow forward"><input type="image"src="an image src" alt="Send Now" 
title=" Send Now "></div>
<div yourface" alt="Back" title=" Back " width="85" height="25"></a></div>
</form>
```

They sent me back the following code as a vulnerability:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="
<s cript>alert('S AINTL2NvbnRhY3RfdX MuaHRtbD9hY3Rpb249c2VuZ CBlbWFpbA==')
</s cri pt>" s ize="40" id="emailaddress " /><s pan clas s ="alert">*</s pan>
<br clas s ="clearBoth" />
```

Code for redrawing $value is the raw post data:

```
 $field = '<input type="' . zen_output_string($type) . '" name="' . 
zen_output_string($name) . '"';
if ( (isset($GLOBALS[$name])) && ($reinsert_value == true) ) {
$field .= ' value="' . zen_output_string(stripslashes($GLOBALS[$name])) . '"';
} elseif (zen_not_null($value)) {
$field .= ' value="' . zen_output_string($value) . '"';
}
if (zen_not_null($parameters)) $field .= ' ' . $parameters;
$field .= ' />';
```

I guess that when the form is submitted an alert should show up on page reload?  I cant seem to trigger this though.  I figure all I need to do is escape the heck out of the value before i repost it to the form to fix it, but now I'm kind of curious what I'm doing wrong that I cant seem to trigger it.  Any one have any ideas how I can reproduce this or what I'm doing wrong?

It is on an old zen cart framework with known vulnerabilities btw.  But I'd like to understand them rather than just install patches.  [Zen function reference](http://www.8tiny.com/source/zencart/nav.html?_functions/index.html)

Comment: You don't actually show any of your code here. How do you expect any useful feedback?

Comment: Notice: The `L2NvbnRhY3RfdX MuaHRtbD9hY3Rpb249c2VuZ CBlbWFpbA==` is the base64-encoded representation of `"/contact_us.html?action=send email"` (without quotes).

Comment: @amber:  what do you need the controller code to see what escaping is being done?

Comment: The rule of thumb is that if your echoing back something to the user eg his name,email,ect that you received from the form &(failed to sanitize) then you should pass it through `htmlentities()` in your view. Also having a stored length of `varchar(255)` or `TEXT` in a table for a name or such content will allow inserting of even larger attack code

Comment: I've tried putting the following into the input and submitting but i cant get it to produce an alert:  <s cript>alert('S AINTL2NvbnRhY3RfdX MuaHRtbD9hY3Rpb249c2VuZ CBlbWFpbA==')
</s cri pt>" s ize="40" id="emailaddress " /><s pan clas s ="alert">*</s pan>
<br clas s ="clearBoth" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is on an old zen cart framework with known vulnerabilities btw. But I'd like to understand them rather than just install patches

Your old site does indeed have known vulnerabilities. A very quick way to see the fix is to grab the code for the new version (which fixed the issue) and compare the files.
There are two files involved:

- /includes/modules/pages/contact_us/header_php.php
- /includes/templates/NAME_OF_YOUR_TEMPLATE/templates/tpl_contact_us_default.php

A quick comparison with WinMerge or your favorite compare tool will point out the differences for you.

There are further system-wide sanitization actions taken elsewhere in the bootstrap core code that also handle related issues.

PS: You really ought to be upgrading to the latest version if you want all those protections ;)

Comment: +1, Glad to see official sources participating with useful information on StackOverflow

Comment: I see.  Thank you for pointing out the files that were patched in that version.  Part of my problem was not knowing exactly where to look.  THe other part of my problem is I actually wanted to take advantage of the exploit myself so I could truly understand the problem before I fixed it.  I was told that this particular site was heavily customized so I opted not to try and upgrade it.

Comment: I would add that there were LOTS of other files patched in that version beyond the two that I mentioned. The ones I mentioned are simply those directly related to the rendering and processing of the page you mentioned. There is more sanitization and XSS protection handled in other core files too, and extends beyond just the files used for model/view activity.